# Check/ Uncheck all checkbox of a Html Table

Tags: javascript, asp.net, checkbox, html-table

I have got a HTML table which contain a check box in `<TH>` and other checkboxes in `<TD>` I want that all `<TD>`'s checkboxes should be checked /unchecked on basis of `<TH>`'s Check box; please help me resolve this. I wrote following code, but its not working:

```
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function SelectAll(id) {

    var frm = document.getElementById('tblemail');

    for (i=0;i<frm.elements.length;i++) {

        if (frm.elements[i].type == "checkbox") {

            frm.elements[i].checked = document.getElementById(id).checked;

        }

    }

} 

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code

```
var frm = document.getElementById('tblemail').getElementsByTagName("input");
var len = frm.length;
var checkedStatus = document.getElementById(id).checked;

for (i=0;i<len;i++) 
{
    if (frm[i].type === "checkbox") 
    {    
        frm[i].checked = checkedStatus;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would consider avoiding looking up the `getElementById` inside the loop. `var checked = document.getElementById(id).checked; for (/* blah blah*/) { frm[i].checked = checked; }`

Answer (score 0):

Have you Tried

```
document.getElementById(id).checked = true
```