# Uncheck all checkbox on pageload using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using following code but it is not working. Tell me if any suggestion. I want all chekboxes unchecked when I load the page. I've got the following code but it doesn't work:

```
 window.onload = function abc() {
     document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].focus();
 }
```

```html
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" ID="cb1" value="29500" onclick="if(this.checked){ cbcheck(this) } else { cbuncheck(this)}" /> Laptop
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="#" id="a1" onmouseover="showimage('a1','laptop1');"  >Show Image</a>
        <img src="Images/laptop.jpg" id="laptop1" alt="" style="display:none; width:150px; height:150px;" onmouseout="hideimage('a1','laptop1');" class="right"/>
    </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>
          <input type="checkbox" ID="cb2" value="10500" onclick="if(this.checked){ cbcheck(this) } else { cbuncheck(this)}" /> Mobile
     </td>
     <td>
          <a href="#" id="a2" onmouseover="showimage('a2','mobile1');"  >Show Image</a>
          <img src="Images/mobile.jpg" id="mobile1" alt="" style="display:none; width:150px; height:150px;"   onmouseout="hideimage('a2','mobile1');" />
     </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: why dont you use jQuery?

Comment: A. If you don't set them to be checked they would be unchecked by default. (Are you afraid of asp.net viewstate or something similar?) B.Focus wouldn't help. set `checked` to be false. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175095/check-uncheck-all-checkbox-of-a-html-table?rq=1) should also help.

Comment: @techie_28, maybe because you don't always need to use jQuery :)

Comment: With the code that you have written, your page should have all the checkboxes unchecked as default.

Comment: By the way why have you kept checkboxes checked?When the page is Initially loading up,Just keep them unchecked by default.

Comment: ya but it didn't work.now  it is working with this code. window.onload = function(){
   var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");

   for(var x=0; x<checkboxes.length; x++)
   {
      if(checkboxes[x].type == "checkbox")
      {
          checkboxes[x].checked = false;
      }
   }

}

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Call this function on your page load event

```
function UncheckAll(){ 
      var w = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); 
      for(var i = 0; i < w.length; i++){ 
        if(w[i].type=='checkbox'){ 
          w[i].checked = false; 
        }
      }
  }
```

Comment: bit mistake in your code it must be if(w[i].type == "checkbox"). As per your code it converts all input tag into checkbox. textbox converts into checkbox when i load the page

Answer (score 8):

You should try

```
window.onload = function(){
   var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");

   for(var x=0; x<checkboxes.length; x++)
   {
      if(checkboxes[x].type == "checkbox")
      {
          checkboxes[x].checked = false;
      }
   }

}
```

and If you can use jQuery, you can try

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked", false);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't see your code attempting to uncheck the boxes. You are only trying to focus on an element.

```
window.onload = function abc() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].focus();
    var a = document.getElementById('form_name').getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
        if (a[i].type == 'checkbox') a[i].checked = false;
    }
}
```

I also advise that you do try out [JQuery](http://jquery.com/). The above code would be just like this in JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#formID input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked',false);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A new answer to showcase new technology. Vanilla JS now in 2015:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
for (var item of list) {
    item.checked = false;
}
```

Compact one-line variation:

```
for(var i of document.querySelectorAll('[type=checkbox]')) { i.checked = false; }
```

This is straight out of [NodeList MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList#Example) examples. The list provided by querySelectorAll is a `NodeList` and the `for...of` loop is a new statement for iterating over property values, a part of 2015 ECMAScript 6 standard—See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Browser_compatibility) for browser compatibility.